# How to arrange windows in Eclipse back into default state?

Tags: eclipse

Is there a function that would arrange windows in Eclipse into state that was previously saved?

I always resize windows (*Package Explorer*, panels with views etc.) based on current needs and then I have to put it back.

Maximizing and minimizing is great but this would be really a killer feature. A click to arrange windows to the desired state would be perfect

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can save your Perspective how you like it and then when that Perspective gets loaded it will come back to the saved state:

*Window > Save Perspective As...*

To reset:

*Window > Reset Perspective...*

Comment: I'm talking about windows arranging, positioning, after you resize them and want them back to the previous state...

Comment: Yes I know, I edited my answer, reset perspective includes window size, position and arrangement.

Comment: Omg I must have had it in the exact same state when I was testing that :-) Thanks citizen conn

Comment: But one is prompted everytime if s/he really wants to reset the perspective, and it looks it can't be turned off

Comment: Is it possible to save the Perspective and restore it in a completely different installation of Eclipse? (say on another PC, where you wish to replicate the look of your previous work space)

Answer (score 3):

Click on windows > Perspective > Reset Perspective

Answer (score 2):

Open new window it will set a default view for eclipse
window->new window